# LAN members Ubuntu machines can't see each other

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking, wireless-router, lan

I have LAN with three ubuntu 12.04 machines. Everyone see only itself and router:

```
nmap -v -sP 192.168.1.2/24 | grep -v "host down"
Nmap scan report for D-link.HomeGateway (192.168.1.1)
Host is up (0.0037s latency).
Nmap scan report for i159 (192.168.1.2)
Host is up (0.00033s latency).
```

So on... I can't get access to other machines via ssh, IPs of the LAN can't ping each other. What is the cause? How to solve?

EDIT: What I have tried so far:

- nmap checking for IPs visibility.
- Ping IPs from each other, try ssh connection.
- sshd_config checking.

I have asked this question on serverfault, but the question was downvoted as offtopic. So, I'll try my fate here.

Comment: Is the problem only with Ubuntu? Do you have the same problem with other operating systems? How is your network setup? Which router do you use?

Comment: I have no machines with other OS. What exactly you need to know about network setup? I use D-Link dsl-2640u.

Comment: "What exactly you need to know about network setup?" Just checking for any unusual network configuration. Have you tried: <http://www.liberiangeek.net/2012/03/enable-ssh-secure-shell-in-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin/>?

Comment: http://www.liberiangeek.net/2012/03/enable-ssh-secure-shell-in-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin/ (Sorry, there was a formatting issue. My bad.)

Comment: 22 port opened on all the machines. I can't ping each other IPs of the LAN, so I believe it is not ssh problem. The 22 port is set in ssh_config.

Comment: Sorry, can't do more for you. This is as far as my Linux networking skills go. Just a general note: Please edit your question with what you have tried so far. It makes it a lot easier to help you. I have made an edit that is waiting for approval. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use ssh on ubuntu you first need to configure it.
 Have a look at this [documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Configuring) for more info

Now since you say pcs cant ping each other that can be very interesting. Try and see in the router settings if you can spot enything like "block broadcast" or any weird firewall config.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but it was google's second suggestion when I searched for a solution to the same problem.  There a few things to try:

- As mentioned in this [answer](https://superuser.com/a/125098/567833) to a similar question "[Can't ping other machines in my network](https://superuser.com/questions/125052/cant-ping-other-machines-in-my-network)" there may be a bug in how the machines (unlikely in this case) or the router is handling WPA2-PSK.
- As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12496260/3708332) you should also check that if your router has the option "Wireless Isolation Within SSID" it is set to *"No*".
- Finally (this is what worked for me) try turning on "Routing Information Protocol" (RIP).  In my Netgear routers this was turned off by default.